# jQuery Hover on Two Separate Elements

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have two separate elements setup which appear on different parts of the DOM - the problem I am facing is that they are absolutely positioned and I can't wrap them in a container div.

I have setup a JSfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sA5C7/1/

What I am trying to do is: move the elements in and out *together* - so that a user can move their mouse between either element and ONLY once they move off BOTH would it hide again ?

How can I set this up? Because at the moment, once I move off a single element - it fires the "leave event" for that element etc.

Comment: fiddle is not working anymore

Comment: just updated it - try this link http://jsfiddle.net/sA5C7/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two boolean variables that you set, each for every element. It gets true when you enter the element and false if you leave.

And only when both are false on leaving => hide the elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bslider = false;
    var btest = false;
    $('#slider').mouseover(function() {
        bslider = true;
        $('#slider, #test').stop(true,false).animate(
                    {'margin-left':'20px'
                    });
    });
    $('#test').mouseover(function() {
        btest = true;
        $('#slider, #test').stop(true,false).animate(
                    {'margin-left':'20px'
                    });
    });
    $('#slider').mouseout(function() {
        bslider = false;
        if(!bslider && !btest)
        {
            $('#slider, #test').stop(true,false).animate(
                    {'margin-left':'0'
                    });
        }
    });
    $('#test').mouseout(function() {
        btest = false;
        if(!bslider && !btest)
        {
            $('#slider, #test').stop(true,false).animate(
                    {'margin-left':'0'
                    });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/vUxeL/ but i can't test if it really works at the moment, jsfiddle seems to be bugged for me.

Comment: Ah the animation was too wild and lost mouseover when animating plus the elements were hidden on the left, i changed the animation up a bit to show how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vUxeL/1/

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works great.  To simplify a bit and give an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/ngb1q3kp/2/

```
$(function(){
    var sliderHover = false;
    var testHover = false;
    $("#slider").hover(function() {
        sliderHover = true;
        doHover();
    }, function() {
        sliderHover = false;
        checkHide();
    });
    $("#test").hover(function() {
        testHover = true;
        doHover();
    }, function() {
        testHover = false;
        checkHide();
    });
    function doHover() {
        $('#slider, #test').stop(true,false).animate({'margin-left':'285px'});
    }
    function checkHide() {
        if (!sliderHover && !testHover) {
            $('#slider, #test').stop(true,false).animate({'margin-left':'0'});
        }
    }
});
```

If you want a more abstracted example. This can easily handle more than two elements:  https://jsfiddle.net/q6o2v8fz/